# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'storeDataFactory.createUser(user).then

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication

the function runs and console.log shows the user object on the backend.  I don't understand why it's telling me there is an issue here, and really need some guidance.

```
vm.register = function() {
    //check that passwords match
  if(vm.password != vm.passwordRepeat) {
    vm.registerError = "Passwords must match.";
    return;
  } else {
    var username = vm.username;
    // console.log("Valid form.  Checking for existing user",username);
    storeDataFactory.userExists(username).then(function(response){
      //if user exists, return error
      if(response.data.length > 0) {
        vm.registerError = "A user with email " + username + " already exists.  Please login.";
        return;
      } else {
        //if no user exists
        if(response.data.length == 0) {
          // console.log("No user exists.  Continue with registration.");
        }
        //assign info to user object
          var user = {
          username: vm.username,
          password: vm.password,
          name: vm.name,
          phone: vm.phone
        };
        **storeDataFactory.createUser(user).then(function(response){**
          vm.user = response.data;
          console.log("Created user", vm.user);
          if(response.data.length > 0) {
            console.log("Created user", vm.user);
            vm.registerMessage = "Successful registration, please login";
            vm.registerError = null;
            vm.user = response.data;  
          }
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
            vm.registerError = "There was an error creating your account.";
            vm.registerMessage = null;
            });  
      }
    });
  }
```

};

The backend code:

```
    module.exports.register = function(req, res) {
  console.log('registering user', req.body);
  //create the user object with hashed pass
  User
    .create({
    username: req.body.username,
    name: req.body.name,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
  }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error creating account");
        res
          .status(400)
          .json(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Account created!", user);
        res
          .status(201)
          .json(user);
      }
    });
};
```

Account created! and the user object are logged on the backend.  It just won't display that damn Successful Registration! Please login. message.

storeDataFactory code:

```
/* global angular */ angular.module('rumbleApp').factory('storeDataFactory', storeDataFactory);

function storeDataFactory($http) {
    return { 
        userExists: userExists,
        createUser: createUser
    };
    function userExists(username) {
        return $http.get('/api/users/userExists/' + username).then(complete).catch(failed);
    }
    function createUser(user) {
        $http.post('/api/users/register', user).then(complete).catch(failed);
    }

    function complete(response) {
        return response;
    }

    function failed(error) {
        console.log(error.statusText);
        return "There was an error with the API call.";
    }

}
```

Comment: did you console the response.data

Comment: Yes, I'm getting no logging after the backend showing that it created the record successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're returning from `storeDataFactory.createUser()`? Can you post the code for that method?

Sounds like the code is executing, but you're not returning anything from it (hence why it thinks it's undefined)

Comment: function createUser(user) {
        $http.post('/api/users/register', user).then(complete).catch(failed);
    }

Comment: function complete(response) {
        return response;
    }
    
    function failed(error) {
        console.log(error.statusText);
        return "There was an error with the API call.";
    }

Comment: There's your problem then, you need to `return $http.post(blahblah)`

Comment: I thought i was doing that with the complete and failed functions in my data factory?

Comment: Doesn't matter what your `complete` function does, because nothing gets passed to it, because you don't return from your `createUser` function! You need to return from your `createUser` function to pass the response as an argument to your `complete` function. Look at your `userExists` function - that is defined correctly. See the difference?